# How to multiply row by constant - google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

in Google Sheets.
Row 1 are all labels. Column 1 are all labels. Both are locked.

Row 2 has unique quantities.
Row 3 is a constant of 0.09.

I want to multiply all of row 2 by row 3,
and have all responses placed under each set, into row 4.

UPDATE:
Can I do this at one time or do I need to go pair by pair?

Tried:

input in cell B4: =B2*B3 -> it worked!
So, now I am wondering: how to multiply ALL of B2*B3? -> input into row 4.

Answer (score 1):

You can put in row 4:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(B2:Z2*B3:Z3)
```

[image]

This will expand to the whole row. Adapt B and Z to the columns you need!

If you can omit row 3, you can just use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(B2:Z2*0.09)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Excel or Google Sheets, multiplication should use the product formula. like

```js
=product(A1:B1)
```

It will work.